# how do I change the mask color of a specific EXT JS Window (popup) (Not across the application, rather just in one window)

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, extjs4.2

I want to change the mast color when a modal window is displayed. I haven't been able to get it working.

I have tried editing .ext-el-mask within the ext-all.css file. I'm able to change the opacity, so I know I'm in the right spot, but as soon as I add background-color: #000 it has not affect.

1. do I modify the css directly in this file or should I be setting up my custom changes in another file if so where?
2. how do I change the background color of the mask, obviously I'm not doing this right.

Any ideas?

I want to change only for the one window.

```
.my-ext-el-mask {
height:100%;
left:0;
opacity:1;
position:absolute;
top:0;
width:100%;
z-index:100;
        }
```

Comment: try to add in loading text the html you want. <div class='div_loader'><span class='span_loader'><img class='img_loader' src='images/loading.gif'/> </span> <span class='span_loader'>Loading...</span> </div>

Answer (score 3):

Its not advisable to directly change extjs source files, instead use your own css style and add it to the required element

Check this fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/196
(css files are also attached in fiddle)